# Sql Server 2008 - Drop a word from the system stop list?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, stop-words

I am trying to drop the "-" character from the stop words list, but I am not able to. I have created my custom stop list which inherits from the system stop list. When I try to delete the "-" from the stop list, sql server tells me that that character is not on the stop list. This is the sql statement I am using:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST "mystoplist" DROP  '-' LANGUAGE 'Brazilian';
```

I have also tried to create a stop list that does not inherits from the system, and it also does not work. At every change I repopulate the catalog, of course.

I guess sql server is using somehow the system stop list also, but I do not know how to delete characters from the system stop list.

What I need is that strings like "blablabla-blablala" (there are some portuguese words that use the "-" character) to be only found when I execute a query like:

```
where contains(field, "blablabla-blablala")
```

And to be never found when I execute a query like:

```
where contains(field, "blablabla")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this is a issue in the word breaker, not in the stop list as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914798/can-i-define-which-word-breakers-to-use-when-building-a-mssql-fulltext-index).

"/" is considered as a word breaker for some languages (included mine).

There is nothing I can do but try to implement my own `IFilter`.