# SQL2008 fulltext index search without word breakers

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, sql-server-2008-r2, wordbreaker

I are trying to search an FTI using `CONTAINS` for Twitter-style usernames, e.g. @username, but word breakers will ignore the @ symbol. Is there any way to disable word breakers? From research, there is a way to create a custom word breaker DLL and install it and assign it but that all seems a bit intensive and, frankly, over my head. I disabled stop words so that dashes are not ignored but I need that @ symbol. Any ideas?

Comment: I found this stack — http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914798/can-i-define-which-word-breakers-to-use-when-building-a-mssql-fulltext-index — but again, the accepted answer leads down a complicated, slippery slope. There's got a be a simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to like this answer. But full text indexes only consider the characters **_** and **`** while indexing. All the other characters are ignored and the words get split where these characters occur. This is mainly because full text indexes are designed to index large documents and there only proper words are considered to make it a more refined search.

We faced  a similar problem. To solve this we actually had a translation table, where characters like *@,-, /* were replaced with special sequences like '**`at`**','**`dash`**','**`slash`**' etc. While searching in the full text, u've to again replace ur characters in the search string with these special sequences and search. This should take care of the special characters.

Comment: Any answer is better than no answer—thanks Torpedo. I will try this out.